# Appending content in a <div> with limited sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my project, I have this `<div>` which receives, via jquery function, the content read from several pages and display them as a popup window:

```
<div id="popup">
    <div id="header"> <span id="title"></span> <span id="button">X</span> </div>
    <div id="text"> </div>
</div>
```

The css associated to this is the following:

```
#popup {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #E0E0E0;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 900px;
    max-width: 1500px;
    max-height: 1000px;
}

#header {
    background-color: #66B2FF; 
}

#title {
    text-decoration-color: #E0E0E0;
    font: 28px arial;
}

#button {
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    min-width: 32px;
    max-width: 5%;
    min-height: 32px;
    max-height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

#text {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #E0E0E0;
    text-decoration-color: #E0E0E0;
    font: 24px sans-serif;
    overflow: auto;
}

.ui-resizable-handle {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

and the content is appended in this `<div>` through this jquery code:

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#popup').draggable({
        cointainment: "#container"
    });

    $('#popup').resizable({
        cointainment: "#container"
    });

    $('#popup').hide();

    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('#popup').hide();
    });

    $('a').click(function(e){
        if($(this).attr('href') != '<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/acesso/logout.html"/>') {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data){
                var $temp  = $('<div/>', {html:data});
                $('#title').text($temp.find('title').text());
                $('#text').html($temp.remove('head').html());
                $('#popup').show();
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

My problem is the content attached to `<div>` being displayed ou of the boundaries of the popup, like this:

[image]

Someone knows how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

new code for the css file:

```
#popup {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #E0E0E0;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
    max-width: 85%;
    max-height: 85%;
}

.ui-resizable-handle {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: red;
}

#header {
    background-color: #66B2FF; 
}

#title {
    text-decoration-color: #E0E0E0;
    font: 28px arial;
}

#button {
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    min-width: 32px;
    max-width: 5%;
    min-height: 32px;
    max-height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

#text {
    overflow: scroll-y;
}
```

Comment: any fiddle of the same?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to solve it:

- Make the popup scroll:

  ```
  #popup {

      overflow:scroll-y;

  }
  ```
- The ideal thing is to make the popup fit the content. But the problem is, that size depends on what is generated inside the popup. If it is predictable, maybe you can define some styles to force the geerated stuff to use relative (%) sizes, in this case your problem is solved. I mean, kind of:

  ```
  #popup {
    position:relative;
    display:block; 
  }

  #popup > div  {

    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
  }
  ```

  This will work if inside `#popup` there's one `div` with the rest of the contents. Find out what's inside to make this fit your needs. You can overwrite styles with the `!important` tag.
- If, on the other hand, you really have no idea what will be inside the popup, or everytime is different, you can detect the size of what's inside via javascript, and adjust `#popup` accordingly. Take a look at `clientHeight` and `clientWidth` properties of DOM elements.

Comment: Ok, I change my css to code added in the topic, but don't accomplish all I wanted. I hope the popup stay in a fixed way, and the content (which is different everytime) be scrolled inside it, at least until I need resize.

Comment: You have to play a little with styles. Obviously without knowing what stuff is generated I can't provide a solution on the blind! If you need a fixed popup with scroll you can set "overflow-y:auto" and that will do the trick. Combine this with forcing styles inside to fit width if possible. You can make experiments with FireBug or Chrome Developer Tools .